# Converting an MP3 from a folder to library to burn on a regular CD?

Tags: windows-7, windows

I have a CD with MP3 files and when I put it into my media player it cannot find the file. It shows in my folders, so how can I get the folders into my music library to burn to a CD?

Comment: It depends on what media player you're using. Is it Windows Media Player (`wmplayer.exe`) or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Among other tools that can do this, [iTunes](http://www.apple.com/itunes/download/) will burn an audio CD for you from MP3 files.